# How do I immediately sync a local folder to a file server when files are changed?

Tags: git, synchronization, sublimetext, githooks, fileserver

I am using Sublime Text 3 to edit code.
I am using GIT for version control.
The application I develop for is only available over CITRIX.
The CITRIX application can only access code on a file server.

At the moment I have my 'local' GIT repo on the file server which CITRIX can access.
This way I can edit and run code immediately.
The problem is that because it is not a local disk, GIT is slow.
I would like the repo to be on a real local disk so GIT is full speed.
I would like to be able to run the working directory code on the CITRIX application.
I don't want to manually start a sync.

I think I want to have some app monitoring my local GIT repo, and immediately and silently sync the tree to the file server on save, move, rename, creation and deletion.
That way it would sync when editing as well as when branch switching.

Another option would be using GIT HOOKS to update the server on checkout, merge, rebase, etc with a Sublimetext plugin to update on working directory saves.

Is there a tool that can do this?
Preferably portable but not essential.
It would be nice to be able to exclude the .git folder.
It is for Windows XP SP3, but the company will soon be upgrading to Windows 7.

I am open to other solutions.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What's wrong with cloning the repo in your local drive and then push-pull changes from/to the CITRIX one?

Comment: That only works for committed files. As I develop, I need to be run and test untracked files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using DSynchorinze. The documentation says it syncs every ten seconds, but that appears to be wrong as it seems to do it almost immediately when files are changed.